# Is it possible to toggle between 2 GUIs from the same Android Activity using a button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, server

I am writing my first android application that consists of a single activity. The activity creates a server, listens for data, decodes and proceesses the data, and displays it. I would like to display the server data two different ways, toggling between them with a button press. (default mode and debugger mode). The server needs to continue running at all times. What is the most simple way to do this?

Mode A: The default for the application. It will just display Icons and relevant information to the user from the messages recieved by the server. Contains a button to toggle mode B.

Mode B: this mode should be triggered when the user taps a button from within mode A. It will hide the information from mode A, and display more in depth information such as raw hex data, and additional information from the message as plain text. Contains a method to toggle back to mode A.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure front end, you can have a fragment placeholder in the activity and switch back and forth between a couple of fragments, each fragment should have a different XML UI layouts as you need your GUI.

Also, pack your layout views from a `ViewModel` in order not to trigger the server while transitioning between fragments.

Comment: Thank you Zain. I implemented the fragments in my application but I am having trouble with the viewmodel. I have my server code in the viewmodel to run and update values within the viewmodel. However when I try to use one viewmodel instance between the two fragments by using their activity's scope I am having trouble. I am trying to use the method from this link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: When I try to access the viewmodel in my fragments using this line: ServerDataViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(ServerDataViewModel.class); and it gives me the following error: error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(Activity)
    constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore,Factory) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: It means that the arguments of the ViewModelProvider constructor are not the same as you do